# Cordova android app text is blur

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using `Cordova` to create an Android application.
I have noticed that when overflow of a div become visible (it is set to auto), the div become blur. This happens only on `Android`. What is the problem?

[Click here to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKjyr.png)
[Click here to see the code](https://hastebin.com/vufinorife.js)

Comment: isn't it a trend when a model gets opened then the back screen or main div behind gets blurred! in the world of HTML AND CSS

Comment: @Rizwanatta The problem is that the back screen or main div behind aren't blurred, but the popup opened is blurred.

Comment: please show us the code of the popup! especially the css

Comment: I have added the code